# Elements on screen look to big on client monitor

Tags: css, media-queries, frontend, screen-resolution

I have client complaining about everything looking "too big" on his website, that "they are all windows 7 and 8 with 27" screens."

His machines with Windows are set at a maximum of 1920x1080, whereas their iMacs' resolutions are at 2560 x 1440. He wants everything to appear the same size as they do on the iMacs.

I went to their office and checked out it out, and indeed, things on their website do look larger on his screen. I see the same situation on websites similar to their site. However, the website is responsive and nothing breaks, the site still looks and works fine--everything just looks bigger.

I suspect this to be a low-res/large-screen issue, but I'm not knowledgeable in hardware to declare this. However, the client is concerned, citing that 27" screens are amongst the most sold on Amazon and Newegg...

Is this a hardware issue that is out of my hands as a front ender, or is there a solution for me to "scale" everything down on screens such as his?

Comment: Do you mean same size relative to the monitor ? Because otherwise 200px by 200px is same size regardless of the monitor resolution.

Comment: 1920x1080 is a crazy low resolution for a 27" monitor. There are crappy 15" laptops that have that resolution.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, buttons, etc, appear larger in physical measurement. For example, on the iMac, each step of the accordion checkout process is visible without scrolling. On the Windows machine, however, when one step is open, the rest is pushed beyond page fold.

Comment: @SteveSanders: Yes, that is my suspicion--large screen + low resolution = everything appearing larger, but I'd like to have more knowledgeable opinions on this.

Comment: Well image size is based on pixels so low resolution on a large screen means that each pixel is more spaced apart. So the image will be larger. You could use centimeters in your CSS to size things so they stay universally the same on all monitors.

Comment: @Dave: That would mean I would have to change just about all units to CM, which doesn't sound quite right? Also, I'm not sure if I'm testing this right, but I set a bordered div box to 5cm, and it stays the same size as the box next to it (189px) no matter what screen I'm using--and none of the boxes on any screen measured to 5cm.

Comment: Well i design so it resizes to the monitor rather than have it a fixed size.

Comment: @Dave: Could you expand on that?
When a user is on a screen with the resolutions 1920x1080 vs 1600x900, how can I tell whether the PPI is any different? The size of the monitor only gives me information of the browser size, but it doesn't tell me how much can be rendered in a given space, right?

Comment: Well i set the dimensions based on %. So for example the logo would be 30% the width of the browser. But you would need javascript to do this, which maybe too much effort than its worth.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for all your input thus far, but I still don'tq uite get what you mean. Could you show me a small example?
What is worth the effort and not is unfortunately not up to me, so I have to find a solution if there is one. If not, I need a sufficient reason why.